# Hive view has no path?

Tags: sql, hadoop, view, hive

I've tried to [make a Hive view](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/AlterView) so we can start sqooping on the columns we need.

The statement used to create the view:

```
CREATE VIEW new_view (col1, col2, col3)
AS SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM source_table;
```

However the view has no perceived location within our Hadoop cluster. What's odd if we run a `SELECT * FROM new_view;` we get the data.

But when we try to run an Oozie job to hook into the view we get a table not found error. The table isn't in file browser either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why you are getting this error is that your view doesn't have any HDFS location to it. Sqoop export looks for `export-dir` but since your view don't contain any location to it, you are getting this error.

A view is just a layer of abstraction on top of your Hive table (which redirects to HDFS location associated to it). Please find below view definition:

> A VIEW statement lets you create a shorthand abbreviation for a more
>   complicated query.The base query can involve joins, expressions,
>   reordered columns, column aliases,and other SQL features that can make
>   a query hard to understand or maintain.It is purely a logical
>   construct (an alias for a query) with no physical data behind it.

You may have to use the `source_table` for `sqoop-export`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a view is a purely logical object with no associated storage.

When a query references a view, the view's definition is evaluated in order to produce a set of rows for further processing by the query.

You can consider reading :- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/AlterView

So you might think of storing the view data in a table in order to access it from oozie.